# JQuery parsing Json file size is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am parsing Json file with JQuery, I got great help from here how to convert .each loop to for loop and the loop itself works, I have other problem, the data.lenght is always undefined and the code does not goes to loop:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
    <script>

    $.getJSON('db.json', function(data) 
    {


    var items = [];
    var i, val;

    console.log(data); //is full and ok
    console.log(data.length); //problem here
    for (i=0; i< data.length; i++) 
    {
        val = data[i];
        if(typeof val === 'object') 
        {
            //doing some stuff
        } 

    }

    });

    </script>
```

The console:

```
Object { @file_name="materials", materials=[10], simulations=[10], more...}
undefined
```

Comment: When you `getJSon` you receive a JSON object, not an array. You need to get the array first (if any) an loop through it. Can you post a (short) sample of data?

Comment: @JScoobyCed: It depends on what the JSON looks like, the top-level entity is allowed to be either an object or an array. But from the output of `console.log`, yes, in this case it's a non-array object.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, I never used it this way, didn't expect that would work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Objects don't have a `length` property (unless you give them one). *Arrays* do, but objects don't.

If you want to loop through the properites of that object, you can use `for-in` loop or jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each).

`for-in` loop:

```
$.getJSON('db.json', function(data) 
{


var items = [];
var i, val;

for (i in data)
{
    val = data[i];
    if(typeof val === 'object') 
    {
        //doing some stuff
    } 

}

});
```

More about `for-in` [on my blog](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html). I'm using it above without worrying about inherited properties because objects deserialized from JSON can't have any enumerable inherited properties.*

`$.each`:

```
$.getJSON('db.json', function(data) 
{


var items = [];

$.each(function(i, val) {
    if(typeof val === 'object') 
    {
        //doing some stuff
    } 

});

});
```

---

* *"...objects deserialized from JSON can't have any enumerable inherited properties."*

That's actually wrong, they can have if someone has added enumerable properties to `Object.prototype`. But anyone doing that in production code should be verbally flogged in public. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Given the console output, it seems the returned value is not an `Array` (of objects), but a single `Object`. Objects don't have a `length` property.